# (Idiomatic?) Difference between new(T) and &T{...}?

Tags: go

I started kidding around with Go and am a little irritated by the `new` function. It seems to be quite limited, especially when considering structures with anonymous fields or inline initialisations.  So I read through the spec and [stumbled over the following paragraph](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables):

> Calling the built-in function new or taking the address of a composite literal allocates storage for a variable at run time.

So I have the suspicion that `new(T)` and `&T{}` will behave in the exact same way, is that correct? And if that is correct, in what situation should `new` be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. `new` is not that useful with structs. But it is with other basic types. `new(int)` will get you a pointer to a zero-valued `int`, and you can't do `&int{}` or similar.

In any case, in my experience, you rarely want that, so `new` is rarely used. You can just declare a plain `int` and pass around a pointer to it. In fact, doing this is probably better because liberates you from thinking about allocating in the stack vs. in the heap, as the compiler will decide for you.

Comment: I must admit that blurring the line between heap and stack allocation is a nice reason to stay away from explicit calls to `new`. But seeing something like `return (&MyStruct{ ... })` still sends shivers down my C++ accommodated spine.

Comment: Even if you use `new`, the compiler can decide to put your variable on the stack if it wants to - this can be more efficient in cases where your variable does not "escape" from the current function. This blurs the heap / stack distinction even further. The stack is good to use because no garbage collection is needed.